# master page javascript load event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

i add a new menu in my master page i should use a javascript function  in master page to setup my menu ,the first time i load the page all work fine but when i click in my menuitem to redirect to another aspx page the setupmenu () function which is in the master didn't work 
this is my code

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.vb"
    Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Qualipro Net</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        function setupmenu() {
            $("#section-menu")
        .accordion({
            "header": "a.menuitem"
        })
        .bind("accordionchangestart", function (e, data) {
            data.newHeader.next().andSelf().addClass("current");
            data.oldHeader.next().andSelf().removeClass("current");
        })
        .find("a.menuitem:first").addClass("current")
        .next().addClass("current");

            $('#section-menu .submenu').css('height', 'auto');
        }
        });
        </script>
         <script  src="js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script  type="text/javascript" src="js/jqPlot/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
        <script  type="text/javascript" src="js/jqPlot/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>
        <script  type="text/javascript" src="js/jqPlot/plugins/jqplot.pieRenderer.min.js"></script>
        <script  type="text/javascript" src="js/jqPlot/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
        <script  type="text/javascript" src="js/jqPlot/plugins/jqplot.highlighter.min.js"></script>
        <script  type="text/javascript" src="js/jqPlot/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.widget.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.accordion.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui/jquery.effects.core.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui/jquery.effects.slide.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <body id="Body1" dir="ltr" runat="server">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
           <asp:Panel ID="panelAModif" runat="server" align="left" CssClass="panelmod">
                    <div class="grid_2">
                        <div class="box sidemenu">
                            <div class="block" id="section-menu">
                                <ul class="section menu">
                                    <li><a class="menuitem">G.R.H</a>
                                        <ul class="submenu">
                                            <li><a >Employés</a> 
                                            </li>
                                            <li><a runat="server"  href="~/employe/RemplacerPersonne.aspx">Remplacer Personne</a> </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a class="menuitem">Documentation</a>
                                        <ul class="submenu">
                                            <li><a>Documents internes</a> </li>
                                     </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a class="menuitem">Audits</a>
                                        <ul class="submenu">
                                            <li><a>Audits</a> </li>

                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a class="menuitem">Actions</a>
                                        <ul class="submenu">
                                            <li><a>Actions</a> </li>
                                            <li><a>Demandes d'actions</a> </li>
                                            <li><a>Modèle d'actions</a> </li>

                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </asp:Panel>
      </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </form>
    </body>
```

i didn't find a solution to call the javascript function from another content page. 
thanks in advance

Comment: Do you get a client side error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First problem:

Your javascript/jQuery script has to occur *after* jQuery is included  or it will not know what `$` means.

e.g in this order:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        function setupmenu() {
            $("#section-menu")
        .accordion({
            "header": "a.menuitem"
        })
        .bind("accordionchangestart", function (e, data) {
            data.newHeader.next().andSelf().addClass("current");
            data.oldHeader.next().andSelf().removeClass("current");
        })
        .find("a.menuitem:first").addClass("current")
        .next().addClass("current");

            $('#section-menu .submenu').css('height', 'auto');
        }
   });
</script>
```

At the moment your jQuery code is the first thing, before even jQuery is included.

### Second problem:

Your `setupmenu` function is declared in the scope of a DOM ready handler, so is not visible to anything outside of that anonymous function!

Put that code outside of any DOM ready handler as it is only called by things that have already waited for DOM ready. This will make it a global function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setupmenu() {
        $("#section-menu")
            .accordion({
            "header": "a.menuitem"
        })
            .bind("accordionchangestart", function (e, data) {
            data.newHeader.next().andSelf().addClass("current");
            data.oldHeader.next().andSelf().removeClass("current");
        })
            .find("a.menuitem:first").addClass("current")
            .next().addClass("current");

        $('#section-menu .submenu').css('height', 'auto');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: this is a problem i fix it but the big problem is :i look for a method to active the function setupmenu() when i go to another page

Comment: thank you @TrueBlueAussie but how i can call this function from another page

Comment: @hamza437: Have you resolved this now? By making it global you can just call it from anywhere. Just make sure the calling code *is* in a DOM ready handler :)

Comment: the problem that it is in the master page i didn't find the way to call it in every load of page